# How to reformat payload response from the backend to the desired format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I change the structure of the payload on the frontend that's coming from the api. Here is the current data structure:

```
{
  listById: [
    [
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7777 - Florida Hurricane'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7777'
        }
      },
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7172'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can I convert it into the following desired structure?

```
{
  list: [
    {
      name: '7777',
      value: '7777 - Florida Hurricane'
    },
    {
      name: '7172',
      value: '7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
formatData = action => {
  const id = action.meta;
  let obj = {...state.listById};
  obj[id] = action.payload;
  let x = {
    ...state,
    listById: Object.values(obj)
  };

  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listById` is an array with another array inside?? Have you tried to use `Array.prototype.map()` ?

```js
// your list
let listById = [
    [
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7777 - Florida Hurricane'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7777'
        }
      },
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7172'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
  
// merge/flatten the arrays and mapping them to the final list
newList = [].concat.apply([],listById).map(o => {
        return {
        name: o["DSTR_NR"].value,
        value: o["Desc"].value
      }
  })
  alert(JSON.stringify(newList))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it can help a bit.

```js
const response = {
  listById: [
    [
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7777 - Florida Hurricane'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7777'
        }
      },
      {
        Desc: {
          value: '7172 - Virginia Severe Storm(s)'
        },
        DSTR_NR: {
          value: '7172'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
   

 const list
     = response.listById ? 
        response.listById[0]?.map(
          ({Desc: {value}, DSTR_NR: {value: name}}) => ({
              name,
              value
        })) 
    : []
const result = {list: list || []}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Andrii, thanks so much. This works really well. I have one question though, if for example let's say that I have another data set coming in with different keys returning from the api such as `ST_NM` and `ST_CD`, how can I use the same logic to get their corresponding values?